# Two API keys with the same name but different access rights

Tags: swagger, openapi

I'm writing the description of my API using OpenAPI 3.

Each account in my system is associated with two API keys, one read-only and one read-write.

All endpoints in my API require one of these keys as the value of the `x-api-key` header. The read-write API key can perform all REST operations (GET, POST, DELETE, etc.) on the endpoints for that account. The read-only key can only be used for GET operations.

How can I enforce this in the schema instead of only describing the behavior in the API description?